# IClassFile annotations

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-jdt

How do you check for Annotations when using IClassFile in Eclipse?

This doesnt seem to work classFile.getClass().isAnnotationPresent? Any help is appreciated.

The problem with using

```
for (final IClassFile classFile : classFiles) {
    IAnnotation[] annotations = classFile.getType().getAnnotations();
```

Is that I have to get All the Packages, then get the Class Files in that package then get the Annotations. It will require 3 loops. Is there a way to minimize this?

Comment: `classFile.getChildren`, search for an element s.t. `element.getType() == IJavaElement.ANNOTATION`

Comment: this does not work.

classFile.getType().getAnnotations() will do.

Comment: my bad. I should have created a separate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that the easiest way for you to find annotations is through a triple loop, but it might be slightly faster (assuming you are looking for a specific annotation) to use a 'SearchEngine`instead.  Take a look at the source code for the`org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.launcher.JUnit4TestFinder` class.  It looks for (source) classes annotated with @Test or @RunWith, which is similar to what you want to do, but for binary classes.

You would do something like this:

```
IJavaElement[] allPackagesToSearch = ...
SearchRequestor requestor = <implement the SearchRequestor abstract class and store all matches>

IJavaSearchScope scope= SearchEngine.createJavaSearchScope(binaryPackages, IJavaSearchScope.APPLICATION_LIBRARIES);
int matchRule= SearchPattern.R_EXACT_MATCH | SearchPattern.R_CASE_SENSITIVE;
SearchPattern runWithPattern= SearchPattern.createPattern("com.foo.MyAnnotation", IJavaSearchConstants.ANNOTATION_TYPE, IJavaSearchConstants.ANNOTATION_TYPE_REFERENCE, matchRule);
SearchParticipant[] searchParticipants= new SearchParticipant[] { SearchEngine.getDefaultSearchParticipant() };
new SearchEngine().search(annotationsPattern, searchParticipants, scope, requestor, new SubProgressMonitor(pm, 2));
```

It's a bit of a mouthful, and to figure out how this works, I'd recommend reading the JavaDoc for SearchEngine, SearchPattern, and SearchRequestor.

If you want to find *all* annotations, then change the match rule, and instead of "com.foo.MyAnnotation", use "*".

Comment: Thanks. going to check this one.